# LiteSpeed crawler - wher put file

Tags: magento2, litespeed

https://docs.litespeedtech.com/lscache/litemage/crawler/

I need to run crawler but im not sure, where I should put this file M2-crawler.sh

This should be in root magento folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a shell script, it does not matter where you put this file. I would recommend again putting it in your Magento root folder in order to keep your Magento root folder clean.

You could download it to your home directory

Then add execute permission

> chmod +x M2-crawler.sh

Then

> bash M2-crawler.sh SITE-MAP-URL